# How does the growing up of trees works with respect to energy conservation?

Tags: mass, energy-conservation, everyday-life, biology

We know that the energy (and hence mass) can neither be created nor destroyed. In the light of above statement, I would like to understand views on growing up of fauna and flora on earth.

A small seed is planted in earth. The only visible input for the seed is amount of manure, fertilizer and water added to it. Agreed, it receives a good amount of energy from sun and other minerals from the earth.

The output: The tree grows up amounting into hundred of tons of wood mass, thousands of flowers and fruits.

Considering that this has been happening for billions of year, Is it fair to assume that the above output is produced from the above set of inputs only and there has been no increase of mass in the process.

Comment: Photosynthesis.

Answer (score 5):

Of course it is. Mass doesn't magically appear out of nowhere.
In the case of a tree, most of the mass is taken out of the air (the carbon from the carbon dioxide) and water (the oxygen and hydrogen).

Comment: This video by Veritasium https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KZb2_vcNTg nicely explains this.

Comment: Looks like mass literally appears out of thin air.

Comment: @Exocytosis True :) but not out of nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

You are exactly right. A plant like a tree is basically a chemical machine for storing chemical energy by converting water and carbon dioxide into cellulose and other hydrocarbons, using solar energy to do the work. Mass is conserved at every step of the process.

Animals then chemically convert plant matter into muscle, bone and brains (in some cases). Mass is strictly conserved here too.

Now since we know that energy has mass via E = mc^2, the solar energy in principle adds mass to any object that stores it up, but the amount of mass increase in a tree via E = mc^2 is millions of times smaller than the mass increase of the tree as it manufactures cellulose and other hydrocarbons, and hence completely negligible in practical terms.